# Slideshow in android viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have problem with android viewpager slideshow. I want to show the viewpager layout after a minimum time period. Here is my code sample. 
**My main class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SwipeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // set the adapter
        adapter = new SwipeAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**My Adapter class:**

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private static int[] mLayouts = { R.layout.view_layout1,
            R.layout.view_layout2, R.layout.view_layout3, R.layout.view_layout4 };

    SwipeAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ViewGroup pageView = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(mLayouts[position],
                container, false);
        container.addView(pageView);
        getItemPosition(pageView);
        return pageView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLayouts.length;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }
}
```

suppose that I want to make the viewpager layout auto sliding after 10 seconds. How can it possible.

Comment: You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/19951862/2987284 for AutoSlide

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to make it auto slide. Here is some code

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            if( position >= 4){
                position = 0;
            }else{
                position = position+1;
            }
            toBarPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
    }
};
```

And don't forget to remove callback `onPause()`

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (handler!= null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to rerun `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Where to get the positionPagerMoved

Comment: It is not necessary for your case, I edited my code. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: And also position always started from zero and edit position>=3. Thanks. Your code works fine.

Comment: where we have to place this handle in main class? if so then in which method

Comment: If user swipes current image with swipe gesture in view pager, how to handle the auto slide show position at that time

Comment: I have implemented the same code. When I switch to next activity and press back then the code crashes. Any idea what must be wrong.

Comment: "Always call the superclass method first". Not Always. For Example, in onDestroy() method.You should call supper class after you've done your things.Look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821481/what-is-the-correct-order-of-calling-superclass-methods-in-onpause-onstop-and-o

Comment: its working.but when position becomes 3 and when loop continues,before showing the first item previous items are showing rapidly.anyone know the reson for this?

Answer (score 1):

use Handler and send[Empty]MessageDelayed/postDelayed and call setCurrentItem on your ViewPager