# How to set viewpager to change page automatically after 5 sec

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slideshow, android-pageradapter

i Want to make a slideshow with viewpager where pages are changed automatically every 5 sec. Ive done the viewpager , but got blocked till here , any advise??

Adapter.class (its inner class in my fragment)

```
 class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_show_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the function i call in my fragment

```
 public void setSlideShow(){

    mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.slide_show);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

}
```

Comment: answerd here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494760/slideshow-in-android-viewpager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, android does not provide any function to automatically flip views inside **ViewPager** but it provides you with something called **TimerTask** class which you can use to achieve your goal.
You can look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610085/how-to-switch-automatically-between-viewpager-pages) to do it this way.

There is one more easy way to achieve this but for that you will have to drop the idea of using **ViewPager**. Instead you can use **ViewFlipper**.
**ViewFlipper** has its own methods to flip automatically. You just need to add these two lines to make your views automatically flippable:

```
mViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
mViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(2000); // flip every 2 seconds (2000ms)
```

You can get **ViewFlipper** example [here](http://codetheory.in/android-viewflipper-and-viewswitcher/).