# How to create image slider with mentioned type in android?

Tags: android, image, slider, android-sliding

I Want to create *change slider one by one with in the time interval* in **android**(like jquery slider).
slider either which will change the image **automatically or manually** user can change. in the below section i add some static content. (with in the page one layout for slider and another one is for my content).
 below i attached the required screen.[image]

Comment: use viewPagerIndicator Library http://viewpagerindicator.com/ and jut start timer.

Comment: @Indiandroid i already seen that example but once that image end then it was stopped. but i need nested once the image view end then it will start from beginning.

Comment: do you mean recursive loop? @Karthik

Comment: @Indiandroid For example i have three images once these three images are completed next it will start from first.. s same as recursive

Answer (score 0):

To achieve pagerview, you need to use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

> I Want to create change slider one by one with in the time interval in android(like jquery slider). slider either which will change the image automatically or manually user can change.

For auto change, implement Runnable with desire interval time, check below link.

[Android ViewPager automatically change page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17167920/646806)