# How to swipe ViewPager images automatically using TimeTask

Tags: android

Hi I am new in android and in my app I have a lot of images in my `ArrayList` that 's 
why I want to swipe those images automatically for every 3 seconds with help of `Timetasker` and this process is continuously need to repeating up to we close app. Can some body help me please

### MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    Integer[] imageId = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};
    String[] imagesName = {"image1","image2","image3","image4"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        PagerAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,imageId,imagesName);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

### CustomAdapter:-

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private Activity activity;
    private Integer[] imagesArray;
    private String[] namesArray;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity,Integer[] imagesArray,String[] namesArray){

        this.activity = activity;
        this.imagesArray = imagesArray;
        this.namesArray = namesArray;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)activity).getLayoutInflater();

        View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(imagesArray[position]);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView1.setText(namesArray[position]);
        ((ViewPager)container).addView(viewItem);

        return viewItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imagesArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return view == ((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);` for changing view pager item

Comment: please read my question clearly for every 3 seconds images automatically need to swipe  them selves and this process need to perform up to we close the app

Comment: please help me with some code

Comment: https://github.com/ajaydewari/AutoSlideViewpager

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167740/android-viewpager-automatically-change-page)**

Add this in your MainActivity.java

```
//...   
int currentPage = 0;
Timer timer;
final long DELAY_MS = 500;//delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed
final long PERIOD_MS = 3000; // time in milliseconds between successive task executions.


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,imageId,imagesName);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    /*After setting the adapter use the timer */
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES-1) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
         }
     };

    timer = new Timer(); // This will create a new Thread 
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, DELAY_MS, PERIOD_MS);
}
```

Comment: feel free to ask any questions in the comment

Comment: what is this currentPage and NUM_PAGES

Comment: currentPage is which page you are currently at. and NUM_PAGES is total number of pages.. in your case its 4

Comment: The code you provided does not reset the timer. I mean when the last page is come up it stops working. It's supposed to run timer again and again... @R.K

Comment: you forgot to use DELAY_MS and PERIOD_MS in your method

Comment: @inverted_index... Hey buddy, the code does return back to the 1st slide from last page. You might have missed the code: "if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES-1) {
                                    currentPage = 0;
                                } "

Comment: I have 4 images scrolling. When once the scrolling is done. It comes to first image where there is a blank page is appearing on which images gets loaded. It is happening with first image only. Any idea?

Comment: The screens are moving too fast. How do I ensure that there is a slow transition from one screen to another?

Comment: @Yesha... You can increase the value for PERIOD_MS in milliseconds.

Comment: When once the scrolling is done and move to pager moving fist page it's look like restat agin how to solve this weird user experience.
Note:View pager with auto change working perfect (Y) just remove that

Comment: `NUM_PAGES-1` should be only `NUM_PAGES` otherwise it will skip the last page.

Answer (score 28):

Here is the code for the automatic scroll the viewpager item:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AutoScrollViewPager viewPager;

    Integer[] imageId = {R.drawable.commitementlogo, R.drawable.like, R.drawable.like_select, R.drawable.plus};
    String[] imagesName = {"image1","image2","image3","image4"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager= (AutoScrollViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.startAutoScroll();
        viewPager.setInterval(3000);
        viewPager.setCycle(true);
        viewPager.setStopScrollWhenTouch(true);

        PagerAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,imageId,imagesName);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

Here AutoscrollViewpager class:

```
public class AutoScrollViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public static final int        DEFAULT_INTERVAL            = 1500;

    public static final int        LEFT                        = 0;
    public static final int        RIGHT                       = 1;

    /** do nothing when sliding at the last or first item **/
    public static final int        SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE      = 0;
    /** cycle when sliding at the last or first item **/
    public static final int        SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_CYCLE     = 1;
    /** deliver event to parent when sliding at the last or first item **/
    public static final int        SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT = 2;

    /** auto scroll time in milliseconds, default is {@link #DEFAULT_INTERVAL} **/
    private long                   interval                    = DEFAULT_INTERVAL;
    /** auto scroll direction, default is {@link #RIGHT} **/
    private int                    direction                   = RIGHT;
    /** whether automatic cycle when auto scroll reaching the last or first item, default is true **/
    private boolean                isCycle                     = true;
    /** whether stop auto scroll when touching, default is true **/
    private boolean                stopScrollWhenTouch         = true;
    /** how to process when sliding at the last or first item, default is {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE} **/
    private int                    slideBorderMode             = SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE;
    /** whether animating when auto scroll at the last or first item **/
    private boolean                isBorderAnimation           = true;
    /** scroll factor for auto scroll animation, default is 1.0 **/
    private double                 autoScrollFactor            = 1.0;
    /** scroll factor for swipe scroll animation, default is 1.0 **/
    private double                 swipeScrollFactor           = 1.0;

    private Handler handler;
    private boolean                isAutoScroll                = false;
    private boolean                isStopByTouch               = false;
    private float                  touchX                      = 0f, downX = 0f;
    private CustomDurationScroller scroller                    = null;

    public static final int        SCROLL_WHAT                 = 0;

    public AutoScrollViewPager(Context paramContext) {
        super(paramContext);
        init();
    }

    public AutoScrollViewPager(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet) {
        super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        handler = new MyHandler(this);
        setViewPagerScroller();
    }

    /**
     * start auto scroll, first scroll delay time is {@link #getInterval()}
     */
    public void startAutoScroll() {
        isAutoScroll = true;
        sendScrollMessage((long)(interval + scroller.getDuration() / autoScrollFactor * swipeScrollFactor));
    }

    /**
     * start auto scroll
     * 
     * @param delayTimeInMills first scroll delay time
     */
    public void startAutoScroll(int delayTimeInMills) {
        isAutoScroll = true;
        sendScrollMessage(delayTimeInMills);
    }

    /**
     * stop auto scroll
     */
    public void stopAutoScroll() {
        isAutoScroll = false;
        handler.removeMessages(SCROLL_WHAT);
    }

    /**
     * set the factor by which the duration of sliding animation will change while swiping
     */
    public void setSwipeScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
        swipeScrollFactor = scrollFactor;
    }

    /**
     * set the factor by which the duration of sliding animation will change while auto scrolling
     */
    public void setAutoScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
        autoScrollFactor = scrollFactor;
    }

    private void sendScrollMessage(long delayTimeInMills) {
        /** remove messages before, keeps one message is running at most **/
        handler.removeMessages(SCROLL_WHAT);
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SCROLL_WHAT, delayTimeInMills);
    }

    /**
     * set ViewPager scroller to change animation duration when sliding
     */
    private void setViewPagerScroller() {
        try {
            Field scrollerField = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scrollerField.setAccessible(true);
            Field interpolatorField = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator");
            interpolatorField.setAccessible(true);

            scroller = new CustomDurationScroller(getContext(), (Interpolator)interpolatorField.get(null));
            scrollerField.set(this, scroller);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * scroll only once
     */
    public void scrollOnce() {
        PagerAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
        int currentItem = getCurrentItem();
        int totalCount;
        if (adapter == null || (totalCount = adapter.getCount()) <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        int nextItem = (direction == LEFT) ? --currentItem : ++currentItem;
        if (nextItem < 0) {
            if (isCycle) {
                setCurrentItem(totalCount - 1, isBorderAnimation);
            }
        } else if (nextItem == totalCount) {
            if (isCycle) {
                setCurrentItem(0, isBorderAnimation);
            }
        } else {
            setCurrentItem(nextItem, true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * <ul>
     * if stopScrollWhenTouch is true
     * <li>if event is down, stop auto scroll.</li>
     * <li>if event is up, start auto scroll again.</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int action = ev.getActionMasked();

        if (stopScrollWhenTouch) {
            if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && isAutoScroll) {
                isStopByTouch = true;
                stopAutoScroll();
            } else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && isStopByTouch) {
                startAutoScroll();
            }
        }

        if (slideBorderMode == SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT || slideBorderMode == SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_CYCLE) {
            touchX = ev.getX();
            if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                downX = touchX;
            }
            int currentItem = getCurrentItem();
            PagerAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
            int pageCount = adapter == null ? 0 : adapter.getCount();
            /**
             * current index is first one and slide to right or current index is last one and slide to left.<br/>
             * if slide border mode is to parent, then requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent false.<br/>
             * else scroll to last one when current item is first one, scroll to first one when current item is last
             * one.
             */
            if ((currentItem == 0 && downX <= touchX) || (currentItem == pageCount - 1 && downX >= touchX)) {
                if (slideBorderMode == SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                } else {
                    if (pageCount > 1) {
                        setCurrentItem(pageCount - currentItem - 1, isBorderAnimation);
                    }
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                }
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        }
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private static class MyHandler extends Handler {

        private final WeakReference<AutoScrollViewPager> autoScrollViewPager;

        public MyHandler(AutoScrollViewPager autoScrollViewPager) {
            this.autoScrollViewPager = new WeakReference<AutoScrollViewPager>(autoScrollViewPager);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            switch (msg.what) {
                case SCROLL_WHAT:
                    AutoScrollViewPager pager = this.autoScrollViewPager.get();
                    if (pager != null) {
                        pager.scroller.setScrollDurationFactor(pager.autoScrollFactor);
                        pager.scrollOnce();
                        pager.scroller.setScrollDurationFactor(pager.swipeScrollFactor);
                        pager.sendScrollMessage(pager.interval + pager.scroller.getDuration());
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * get auto scroll time in milliseconds, default is {@link #DEFAULT_INTERVAL}
     * 
     * @return the interval
     */
    public long getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    /**
     * set auto scroll time in milliseconds, default is {@link #DEFAULT_INTERVAL}
     * 
     * @param interval the interval to set
     */
    public void setInterval(long interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    /**
     * get auto scroll direction
     * 
     * @return {@link #LEFT} or {@link #RIGHT}, default is {@link #RIGHT}
     */
    public int getDirection() {
        return (direction == LEFT) ? LEFT : RIGHT;
    }

    /**
     * set auto scroll direction
     * 
     * @param direction {@link #LEFT} or {@link #RIGHT}, default is {@link #RIGHT}
     */
    public void setDirection(int direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    /**
     * whether automatic cycle when auto scroll reaching the last or first item, default is true
     * 
     * @return the isCycle
     */
    public boolean isCycle() {
        return isCycle;
    }

    /**
     * set whether automatic cycle when auto scroll reaching the last or first item, default is true
     * 
     * @param isCycle the isCycle to set
     */
    public void setCycle(boolean isCycle) {
        this.isCycle = isCycle;
    }

    /**
     * whether stop auto scroll when touching, default is true
     * 
     * @return the stopScrollWhenTouch
     */
    public boolean isStopScrollWhenTouch() {
        return stopScrollWhenTouch;
    }

    /**
     * set whether stop auto scroll when touching, default is true
     * 
     * @param stopScrollWhenTouch
     */
    public void setStopScrollWhenTouch(boolean stopScrollWhenTouch) {
        this.stopScrollWhenTouch = stopScrollWhenTouch;
    }

    /**
     * get how to process when sliding at the last or first item
     * 
     * @return the slideBorderMode {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE}, {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT},
     *         {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_CYCLE}, default is {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE}
     */
    public int getSlideBorderMode() {
        return slideBorderMode;
    }

    /**
     * set how to process when sliding at the last or first item
     * 
     * @param slideBorderMode {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE}, {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_TO_PARENT},
     *        {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_CYCLE}, default is {@link #SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE}
     */
    public void setSlideBorderMode(int slideBorderMode) {
        this.slideBorderMode = slideBorderMode;
    }

    /**
     * whether animating when auto scroll at the last or first item, default is true
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isBorderAnimation() {
        return isBorderAnimation;
    }

    /**
     * set whether animating when auto scroll at the last or first item, default is true
     * 
     * @param isBorderAnimation
     */
    public void setBorderAnimation(boolean isBorderAnimation) {
        this.isBorderAnimation = isBorderAnimation;
    }
}
```

here CustomDurationScroller class:

```
public class CustomDurationScroller extends Scroller {

    private double scrollFactor = 1;

    public CustomDurationScroller(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomDurationScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator) {
        super(context, interpolator);
    }

    public void setScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
        this.scrollFactor = scrollFactor;
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, (int)(duration * scrollFactor));
    }
}
```

and set the adapter same as you previously set.

Comment: You can find demo from here https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager

Comment: This answer worked me, but MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked is deprecated

Answer (score 5):

Here is the total code using `TimerTask`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;

Integer[] imageId = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};
String[] imagesName = {"image1","image2","image3","image4"};

Timer timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,imageId,imagesName);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewPager.post(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem((viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1)%imageId.length);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 3000, 3000);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: Possible DIVIDE BY ZERO ERROR HERE `                    `viewPager.setCurrentItem((viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1)%imageId.length);`
when dynamically filling the imageId array. so we  use                     `viewPager.setCurrentItem((viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1)%imageId.length+1);`

Answer (score 4):

Create handler in activity, then schedule a task. I think Handler is enough for this small task. Don't go for timer.

```
Runnable timeCounter = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                 if((currentIndex+1)>imageId.length() ){
                      currentIndex=0;
                  }else{
                      currentIndex++;
                 }
                ViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentIndex);
                handler.postDelayed(timeCounter, 3*1000);

        }
    };
handler.postDelayed(timeCounter, 3*1000);
```

then in onDestroy() or where ever you want to stop

```
handler.removeCallbacks(timeCounter);
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to create handler and how to call

Comment: In your activity where you create variables. just copy below code.
Handler handler = new Handler();

Answer (score 4):

using Kotlin coroutine

```
      val totalPages = 3

       CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        while (isActive) {
            delay(1500)
            if (viewPager.currentItem + 1 > totalPages-1) {
                viewPager.currentItem = 0
            } else {
                viewPager.currentItem++
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a very simple and perfectly working answer

Answer (score 2):

Another version of the answer:-

```
                    private int currentPage = -1;
                    // start auto scroll of viewpager
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(++currentPage, true);
                            // go to initial page i.e. position 0
                            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES -1) {
                                currentPage = -1;
                                // ++currentPage will make currentPage = 0
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    timer = new Timer(); // This will create a new Thread
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            handler.post(Update);
                        }
                    }, 500, 1500);
```

Answer (score 2):

a simple edit to @L. Swifter's code snippet for the ones wondering about variables, I wrapped it all in a method which you can add to your activity after setting the adapter

```
private void automateViewPagerSwiping() {
    final long DELAY_MS = 500;//delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed
    final long PERIOD_MS = 3000; // time in milliseconds between successive task executions.
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == adapter.getCount() - 1) { //adapter is your custom ViewPager's adapter
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
            else {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
            }
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(); // This will create a new Thread
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(update);
        }
    }, DELAY_MS, PERIOD_MS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution to show a series of images automatically try the ViewFlipper in your xml file. Not suitable for all purposes, but I found it to be a useful solution to something I was putting together.

```
 <ViewFlipper
android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:autoStart="true"
android:flipInterval="2000" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture1" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture2" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture3" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture4" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/picture5" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto swipe ViewPager in Kotlin, simple and easy code.(if you have only 2 page)

```
val handler = Handler()
val update = Runnable {
       viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage % 2, true);
       currentPage++
      }
var timer = Timer()// This will create a new Thread
    timer!!.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
         override fun run() {
         handler.post(update)
         }
   }, 500(DELAY_MS), 3000(PERIOD_MS))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
In MainActivity -

```
int currentIndex=0; //for tracking current item
```

Create and set your TimerTask as per your requirement then in `run()` of TimerTask:

```
public void run() {
    if((currentIndex+1)>imageId.length() ){
      currentIndex=0;
    }else{
      currentIndex++;
    }
    ViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int ci=0;
 java.util.Timer timer;
 timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Log.d("viewPager",""+ci);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(ci%7);
                    ci++;

                }
            });
        }
    },1000,5000);
```

it updates every 5seconds(5000)

Answer (score 0):

You can use android `TabLayout` for indicators, `ViewPager` for slide screen and `TimerTask` to slide automatic

please check this link for step by step guideline and demo

[**CLICK HERE**](https://medium.com/@shaktisinh/auto-slider-with-indicator-in-android-a28153d42125)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your onCreate() method

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int currentPage=viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            //return to first page, if current page is last page  
            if (currentPage == titleNames.length-1) {
                currentPage = -1;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(++currentPage, true);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(runnable);
        }
    },DELAY,PERRIOD)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use ViewFlipper instead of viewpager

Layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/imageFrames"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark" >
</ViewFlipper>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/slideShowBtn"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Activity

```
public class SlideShowActivity extends Activity  {



ViewFlipper imageFrame;
Button slideShowBtn;
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo_slideshow_main);
    imageFrame = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.imageFrames);

            //get sd card path for images

    File parentFolder = new
     File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     .getAbsolutePath()
     + "/images");

    addFlipperImages(imageFrame, parentFolder);

    handler = new Handler();
    imageFrame.setOnClickListener(SlideShowActivity.this);

    slideShowBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideShowBtn);
    slideShowBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            runnable = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
                    imageFrame.showNext();

                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
        }
    });

}

private void addFlipperImages(ViewFlipper flipper, File parent) {
    int imageCount = parent.listFiles().length;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    for (int count = 0; count < imageCount - 1; count++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        Bitmap imbm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(parent.listFiles()[count]
                .getAbsolutePath());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imbm);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        flipper.addView(imageView);
    }

}

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}
}
```