# How to create Android Auto Image Slider with round Indicator using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to implement image slider in android using only kotlin language. I need auto slider with dot indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewpager2 to have auto image slide and for round indicator you need to make a drawable.

```
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
```

[Video Tutorial for reference,](https://youtu.be/6HUsPmV5xYY) this is exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472916/how-to-swipe-viewpager-images-automatically-using-timetask) its a java code only, but after adding the file, convert to kotlin using android studio tool, double shift and search for "convert java to kotlin"